# Skin Modifier not working

Tags: modifiers

I am new to the blender community and cg in general,

today, I was trying to do this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AO45Q_rgw8k but I am stuck at 7:09, which is the skin modifier part.

When I apply the skin modifier to my mesh (which is an extruded single vert) the modifier will only affect a part of the mesh and the other part will stay as a segment.

REFERENCE:
[image]

[image]

MY WORK:
[image]

[image]

As you can see in the pictures, the part that is supposed to be the trunk isn't affected by the modifier, if you have any idea what this is, please respond.

Here is the blend: https://blend-exchange.com/b/5paBM4aV

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you tapped on "mark root" when you had the lowest vertex selected.

To solve this, just tap on that vertex here:

[image]

and tap on "mark root"

[image]

then you get:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked!!

Comment: please check the checkmark left to my answer if it was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: so what Mark Root is for?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html

Comment: it's almost more incomprehensible than before  ^^

Comment: 